# getting java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java

I am creating a remote api using spring tool suite api and when running my code I keep getting an error. Been trying to figure out the problem, for hours but can't seem to figure it out.

Error Message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders cannot be cast to class lombok.var (org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders and lombok.var are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.ncr.aem.controller.ViewIncidentsController.getAllSummary(ViewIncidentsController.java:462)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    ... 40 more
```

I believe the issue is due to the type casting in the below code snippet:

Code Snippet:

```
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  responseHeaders.set("Baeldung-Example-Header", 
          "Value-ResponseEntityBuilderWithHttpHeaders");
    var headers = (var) new HttpHeaders();
```

I am thinking I will need to cast the the HttpHeaders object using the correct data type. I am not too sure what that data type is for the HttpHeaders object. any ideas will be helpful

Comment: ```var headers = (var) new HttpHeaders();```   why are you casting the HttpHeaders to `var` ? var is not a type

Comment: yes, var means that it can take any type. I am now using java 8 which doesn't allow var so the error message is popping up

Comment: If you are using Java 8 then you cannot use the `var` keyword; importing something else that happens to be called `var` (in this case, `lombok.var`) is not going to solve your problem. Use `HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();` instead, if this needs to work on Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messsage already describes what's wrong:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders cannot be cast to class lombok.var (org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders and lombok.var are in unnamed module of loader 'app')`

Here, you are trying to cast the HttpHeaders to `var` type. `var` is not a type(a class)

```
  var headers = (var) new HttpHeaders();
```

> I am not too sure what that data type is for the HttpHeaders object.
> any ideas will be helpful

How about `var headers = new HttpHeaders();`. IDK why you needed to cast it in the first place?

Or, `HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();`